# angularJS update array in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am trying to update a part of an ng-repeat that has an nested ng-repeat inside, like this example:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
   <div ng-repeat="color in product.colors"></div>
</div>
```

the information comes from a combined array.

```
Array colors
Array products
```

and is merged into one array that looks like this:

```
{ 
 product:"car", 
 brand:"volvo", 
 colors: {
        front: "red",
        roof: "yellow",
};
```

how would i be able to update the `$scope.colors` and with that see the effect of the update in the `ng-repeat` appear (add another color) without updating the complete `$scope.products` of course, that will rebuild the whole thing

Comment: With JavaScript literals defined with curly brackets `{ }` are objects. Literals with square brackets `[ ]` are arrays.

Comment: sorry mix-up :)

Answer (score 0):

> how would i be able to update the `$scope.colors` and with that see the effect of the update in the `ng-repeat`

Use `angular.copy`:

```
angular.copy(new_object, $scope.colors);
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS angular.copy Function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Answer (score 0):

alright, instead of updating the actual scope, i added 'track by product.ID'

```
ng-repeat="product in products track by product.ID"
```

this prevents the complete structure rebuilding each time and now when i update the colors array and reinitiate the products scope it updates just colors